# Python - Searching index of lists in list containing one element

Tags: python, list

I have a list L of 4-length list

```
L = [[1,2,12,13],[2,3,13,14],...]
```

and two integers a and b which appear many times in the sublists. What I want is to find the index of the sublists in L which contain a AND b.

I wrote a little code

```
l=[]
for i in range(len(L)):
    if L[i][0]==a or L[i][1]==a or L[i][2]==a or L[i][3]==a:
        l.append([i] + L[i]) # I put the index in the first position.
# Now l is a list of 5-length lists.
# I do the same loop on that list.
r=[]
for i in range(len(l)):
    if l[i][1]==b or l[i][2]==b or l[i][3]==b or l[i][4]==b:
        r.append(i)
```

The index I am looking for are in the list r. However I am pretty sure there is another way to do it in Python since I barely know this language. Maybe if my variable L is something else than a list of lists it would be easier/faster, because I will call this procedure a lot in my main program. (len(L) is around 3000)

By the way I know that the number of index is between one and four included, so I could put some break but I don't know if it will be faster.

---------------- EDIT 1 ----------------

Change "a or b (or is inclusive)" to "a AND b" in the second sentence. I wrote a mistake about my goal.

Comment: Can you describe your problem a little more. What are you trying to do and what is wrong with your current approach? Is it really too slow?? (How long is `L`?) Also, in your current code `r` is a list of lists that contain both `a` AND `b` -- not inclusive or.

Comment: I need the index of each sublists in the main list L, which contains a or b or a and b. My code gives me the right answer but since I barely know the Python language I am sure there is a faster way to do it. The main list L is about 3000 long, and each sublist is 5 long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
for index, item in enumerate(L):
  if a in item or b in item:
    r.append(index)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
r = [i for i,x in enumerate(L) if any(y in x for y in (a,b))]
```

enumerate will give you both indices and values in your list comprehension, and the any statement will tell you if either a or b are in x, which is a sublist in L

Answer (score 0):

Use [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) to test the sublists:

```
if any(a in subl for subl in L):
```

This tests each `subl` but exits the generator expression loop early if a match is found.

This does *not*, however, return the specific sublist that matched. You could use [`next()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) with a generator expression to find the first match:

```
matched = next((subl for subl in L if a in subl), None)
if matched is not None:
    matched[1] += 1
```

where `None` is a default returned if the generator expression raises a `StopIteration` exception, or you can omit the default and use exception handling instead:

```
try:
    matched = next(subl for subl in L if a in subl)
    matched[1] += 1
except StopIteration:
    pass # no match found
```

Comment: matched = next((subl for subl in L if a in subl), None) gives only one sublist which contains a ; how can I tell Python to continue to search ? And I need the index because it would be silly to write as the final line L.index(matched)

Answer (score 0):

This kind of thing is what list comprehension is made for.

If you really want inclusive or -- then this is the list you want. In your code, currently, you've giving and.

```
result = [a_tuple for a_tuple in L if a in a_tuple or b in a_tuple]
```